# Where can I find good examples or tutorials for sqlalchemy-migrate

Tags: sqlalchemy, pylons, data-migration, sqlalchemy-migrate

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165452/how-to-efficiently-manage-frequent-schema-changes-using-sqlalchemy) someone pointed me to use **sqlalchemy-migrate** to help with a fast-changing web application using sqlalchemy. 
However a [Do It Yourself method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165452/how-to-efficiently-manage-frequent-schema-changes-using-sqlalchemy/4165496#4165496) was also recommended consisting in manually writing CSV columns for the new database schema, and finally import them.

The problem is that I can't find **real-world examples of sqlalchemy-migrate**. Ressources that I have found [at best](http://truefalsemaybe.com/2008/09/sqlalchemy-migrations/) decribe adding a single column or a column rename. The official documentation essentially describes the API and it's hard to see how to use migrate effectively. From the doc I cannot even know if migrate could **help changing the database engine**, from sqlite to mysql for example, while the DIY solution would to the job.

I really want to see code that would make some **non-trivial transformations of a database schema** and proving that migrate is really a useful tool.

Where can I find good examples/tutorials for sqlalchemy-migrate ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget about google code search when looking for real work examples of code. For instance the follow search:

http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=%22from+migrate+import%22+lang:python&sbtn=Search

Will pull up a number of real migration scripts. It basically looks for Python files with "from migrate import" in the file.

Work through some of these and see if you can follow what they're doing.