# Test whether DB migration result are consistent with (ORM)? models

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, migrate, sqlalchemy-migrate

I am using `migrate` to create SQL database schema and populate it with initial data.  Later SQLAlchemy is used to work with this DB.

How could I test that my `SQLAlchemy` models are relevant/correct for real DB schema generated by `migrate`?

Comment: Do a migrate again and filecompare? Heres an extensive help btw: https://sqlalchemy-migrate.readthedocs.org/en/v0.7.2/versioning.html

Comment: FYI, if you are still using `sqlalchemy-migrate`, you should switch to `alembic` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209705/is-it-worth-using-sqlalchemy-migrate).

Comment: @Alfons Yes, but how will I know that my DB after all migrations exactly matches SQLAlchemy models?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it, but in the features list, this tool seems to do want you want:

http://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Translator::Manual

*FINDING THE DIFFERENCES BETWEEN TWO SCHEMAS
As mentioned above, the "sqlt-diff" schema examines two schemas and creates SQL schema modification statements that can be used to transform the first schema into the second. The flag syntax is somewhat quirky:

$ sqlt-diff foo-v1.sql=MySQL foo-v2.sql=Oracle > diff.sql*

main tool page:
http://sqlfairy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This may be a way to go - just compare schemas, generated by different approaches.  Thanks, will take a look on this.