# Relative importing python module from a subfolder from a different subfolder

Tags: python, import, python-module, alembic

I'm trying to use alembic which is an sqlalchemy tool in python. You type a command and it generates a folder "alembic" with py files inside. The py file inside, needs to link to my application in a separate folder called "myapp". But I cannot link it. It says it doesn't exist and relative import doesn't work.

so I need to import my config class from **myapp/configs/config.py** file.

```
/apps
+--/alembic
|----env.py <--- the calling file
+--/myapp
|----configs/__init__.py <--- has "DefaultConfig" class imported
|----configs/config.py <--- I want to import the class inside here.
```

inside env.py:

```
from myapp.configs import DefaultConfig
```

Doesn't work.

I tried:

```
from ..myapp.configs import DefaultConfig
```

No success.

example code in alembic docs say just use "myapp.whatever".

I even added my "/apps" and "/myapp" to PYTHON_PATH in environment variables.

Example error:

```
File "D:\apps\myapp\lib\site-packages\alembic\command.p
y", line 97, in revision
    script.run_env()
  File "D:\apps\myapp\lib\site-packages\alembic\script.py
", line 191, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, 'env.py')
  File "D:\apps\myapp\lib\site-packages\alembic\util.py",
 line 186, in load_python_file
    module = imp.load_source(module_id, path, open(path, 'rb'))
  File "alembic\env.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..myapp.configs import DefaultConfig as conf
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Comment: I'm confused, did you run setup.py for the project?

Comment: After I pip install alembic... I did "alembic init alembic" and it generated the files.

Comment: Try appending `'../myapp'` to Python's `sys.path` in env.py before the import.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two possible solutions to your problem:

### Modify your PYTHONPATH environment variable

Add the path to apps catalogue by running following BASH / SH shell commands in your terminal:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:'/path/to/apps'
```

Please not that adding it to the PATH environment variable won't work. To find out more about PYTHONPATH, how to manage it plus nice and friendly info on modules in general:

http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath

Please note however that this approach does affect your system's PYTHONPATH. It is highly recommended to use a virtualenv - just in case things go wrong, it won't affect all your system and other apps. When using virtualenvwrapper:

```
$ add2virtualenv '/path/to/apps'
```

More [HERE](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#add2virtualenv).

### Append path from inside the Python script

Alternatively, you can do the same but just for a script runtime by adding:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/apps')
```

to your `apps/alembic/env.py` file.

Finally, in same file, make a following change:

```
from myapp.configs.config import DefaultConfig
```

And please note that your `apps/myapp` folder should also contain `__init__.py` file (might be empty) to make Python to treat is as a module as Demian Brecht pointed out.

Comment: Worked for me! Is the alembic folder supposed to be inside of the application module by default? That seems like a strange behavior. Also, to avoid that hard path

`import sys,os

sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
`

Answer (score 0):

Is `myapp` a self-contained application, or a sub-application such as ones that you can find using Django? If it's a self-contained app, then you're kinda going about things wrong. What you really want to do is to install the dependencies that your app has in order to be able to access them without having to use relative imports and the like (which is bad practice, *especially* if anyone but you is using the app).

What you likely will want to do (again, if it's self-contained):

- Set up a virtual environment for your app (I *highly* recommend the use of virtualenvwrapper, which I just wrote about in my shiny new (and incomplete) blog: http://demianbrecht.github.com/posts/2013/01/02/virtualenvwrapper/
- Install `alembic` as a dependency: `pip install alembic`
- Create a `requirements.txt` file: `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Now, you should be able to use alembic via `import alembic` from anywhere within your project.

**Edit**:

Your directory structure is also a little wonky. You'll want to put all of your app-specific modules into another `myapp` subdirectory:

```
myapp
    myapp
        __init__.py
        configs/__init__.py
```

The reason for this is so that you can add `myapp` to your `PYTHONPATH` and be able to import any modules from your app via `from myapp import foo`. As it stands, if `myapp` is on your `PYTHONPATH`, you'll only be able to access the submodules from the second namespace level (i.e. `import configs`), which is bad for obvious reasons.

Comment: It's a Flask app. Well I am not sure of how else to get alembic to find my config file and get the DB SQL URI from it. The example says to just do "app.config["SQLALCHEMY_URI"] or something, but it doesn't define how to get "app". The error being thrown is AFTER I run 'alembic revision --autogenerate -m "test"' just so I can create my initial models.

Comment: You can use ``from flask get current_app`` to get ``app`` as long as you're in request context.

Comment: Well you would only use alembic when executing commands while the website is even offline, so it would have to be application context. I think I need some new code like in flask-alembic